# How to compare values from two views

Tags: views

I have two views, "viewA" and "viewB;" "viewA" contains all the users that post within the day, and "viewB" contains all the users. I need to get the difference between the two so I can get the users that don't have any post. I could use `views_get_view_result()` and `views_get_current_view()`, but I don't know how to implement the code.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to compare the result of two views and find the difference, which is highly inefficient and difficult, it will be a lot easier to create a new view that filters out the users that that has posted within a day.

You should be able to duplicate ViewA and reverse it's filter(s). It should at least provide a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You could load the view-results and compare them with a helper like this:

```
function _get_view_result($view_name,$display,$argument) {
    $view = views_get_view($view_name);
    $view->set_arguments(array($argument));    // only if you have arguments
    $view->set_display($display);
    $view->pre_execute();
    $view->pager['items_per_page'] = 0; // get all items (only if you have a pager)
    $view->execute();
    return $view->result; 
}
```

Afterwards you can compare them the way you like. But in many cases you are better off with a seperate view for such things.

Comment: What I'm trying to implement is how to create a list of users that have post within the day and users that dont have post. Some sort of post monitoring.
Is there a module that have this functionality? Or I can create 2 views, that views A contains users that have post and view b that contains all users. Getting their difference will also get the users that dont have post.

Thanks guys for giving insights

Comment: by the way im using views 3